# How to apply wp_enqueue_script to all posts in wordpress

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, tableofcontents

I found a tutorial online which shows how to use a table of content in WordPress. There is a code and the code is

```
if ( is_page( 'tocbot' ) ) {

    wp_enqueue_script(
        'tocbot',
        plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'assets/js/tocbot.min.js',
        array(),
        '4.3.1',
        true
    );

} // End if().
```

The developer said that we need to replace **is_page( 'tocbot' )** with your desired if conditional depending on where you want to use Tocbot.

I found the tutorial [here](https://wpdevdesign.com/automatic-table-of-contents-using-tocbot-in-oxygen/)

Answer (score 0):

Use `is_sgingle()` insted of `is_page()`.

```
if ( is_sgingle() ) {

    wp_enqueue_script(
        'tocbot',
        plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'assets/js/tocbot.min.js',
        array(),
        '4.3.1',
        true
    );

} // End if().
```

Answer (score 0):

List of all WordPress conditionals is [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags).

In your case for all posts it is will be `is_single`. For posts, pages and post types it is `is_singular`.